# How to detect input text - Floating label input (React)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, input

I'm building a floating label input (in React) but I'm having difficulty detecting text on it.
If the user clicks on the input but does not enter anything, the label stays at the top of the screen, its doest bounce back.
I tried a few things already but no success.

Here is what I got so far:

```
      const [text, setText] = useState();
      const [hasText, setHasText] = useState();
```

---------having issues with this part------------

```
 const formula = () =>{
      if(setHasText === " "){
          setText(true)
          
      } else{
          setText(false)
      }
      
  }
```

---

```
<View style={{ 
         width: '100%',
    height: 64,
    marginVertical:16,
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 5,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray'
    
    }}>
    
    <Text style={{
        position: 'absolute',
        left:20,
        top: !text ? 20 : 2,
        fontSize: !text ? 18 : 14,
        color: !text ? 'black' : 'black',
    fontWeight:!text ? '400' : '600',
    fontStyle:'normal',
    }}>Info</Text>
         
      <TextInput 
      value={setHasText}
      style={{ fontSize:18, marginTop:8,}} 
      onFocus={()=> setText(true)}
      onBlur={formula}
      onChangeText={setData}/> 
      </View>
```

The onChangeText={setData} is grabbing data for an api and the value={setHasText} is my attempt to detect text in the input.

###### The goal is:

I'd like to detect text in the input so my floating label works properly.

Here is also some print screens of the input.

[image: Input view]

This is how I would like it to stay once I click out of the input
[image: Input with text]

[image: When I click out :(]

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: `if(setHasText === " ")`?? Shouldn't it be `if(hasText === " ")`?

Comment: It doesn’t work unfortunately. When I click out of the input box, the label get stuck at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Try change setHasText to hasText

Comment: Already tried that, it doesn’t work unfortunately:(

Comment: try this function 
const formula = () =>{
      if(hasText === ""){
          setText(true)
          
      } else{
          setText(false)
      }
     
  }